# Where did Iron Man 2 take place?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-2

During *Iron Man 2*, the Stark Expo is pretty clearly modeled on the [New York World's Fair grounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flushing_Meadows). Tony and Happy are able to drive from Stark Expo to Washington D.C. in a few hours (at most, overnight). And late in the film, when tracing Vanko's phone call to Stark, the trace shows the call get traced to Hammer Industries in New York City.  Meanwhile, it's already established that Stark lives in Malibu, and much of the film occurs at his house.

There's no indication that there's a large distance between Stark Expo, Hammer Industries, and Stark's home. But there are *implied* vast distances between some of these locations.  Where did the film take place?  Is it supposed to have taken place on both the East and West coasts?

Comment: I thought it was in *Las Vegas*, but this may be just the glamorous staging of the *Stark Expo* (and I don't remember it that well either). But in the end I guess you can travel to any location inside the US overnight when going by plane.

Comment: Some of the scenes were filmed at [SpaceX Factory](http://www.popularmechanics.com/science/space/rockets/inside-spacex-we-visit-the-companys-california-headquarters-2#slide-2). SpaceX is a Space Exploration Private Company based in California.

Comment: I'll do you one better: *why* did *Iron Man 2* take place?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Stark Expo occurs in Flushing Meadows, New York which you could drive to D.C. in a few hours. Tony does live in Malibu as displayed in the movie as well as for Hammer Industries which is in Queens, NY.

Source: [http://www.starkexpo2010.com/](https://web.archive.org/web/20141231043212/http://www.starkexpo2010.com/) and http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Stark_Expo

Stark Expo was filmed in L.A. Live, Downtown, Los Angeles, California, USA

Source: [IMDB locations](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1228705/locations)